# Obtaining version of youtube android app

Tags: android, youtube

I guys,
is there a method to find what version of the youtube player installed in my phone thru java code?

Thanks.

Comment: may I ask why you want know the version of youtube app?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
String versionName = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("youtube's package name as String", 0 ).versionName;
int versionCode = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("youtube's package name as String", 0 ).versionCode;
```

Make sure to wrap this in a `try-catch` block for the `NameNotFoundException` incase YouTube isn't installed on the user's device.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. With the class `PackageInfo` (ref: [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html))

```
// The version number of this package, as specified by the <manifest> tag's
// versionCode attribute. Added in API level 1
public int versionCode 

// The version name of this package, as specified by the <manifest> tag's
// versionName attribute. Added in API level 1
public String versionName
```

code:

```
PackageInfo pinfo = null;
pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.google.android.youtube", 0);
int versionNumber = pinfo.versionCode;
String versionName = pinfo.versionName;
```